# Charging a payment via Java Visa API

Tags: java, visa-api

I need to be able to charge (say, 1 dollar) from a user. The user supplies:

1. Card number (4 digit groups each 4 digits long),
2. Expiration month and year
3. CVC

What I want to accomplish is to charge an amount of money from the user. How can I do it using Visa Java API?

Comment: Did you check the base http api ? If the feature is not provided, no one sdk would help you.  https://developer.visa.com/apibrowser  https://developer.visa.com/pages/working-with-visa-apis/visa-developer-quick-start-guide